# Flask-SQLalchemy update the current_user

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How would I update the current users firstname and lastnames in my Flask-SQLAlchemy database?

I have tried to use the following code based off of the flask-sqlalchemy documentation - however, it only commits the update for the email field and does not update the record for either the firstname or lastname fields.

```
# views.py
@users.route("/account", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():

    form = UpdateUserForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        current_user.firstname = form.firstname.data
        current_user.lastname = form.lastname.data
        current_user.email = form.email.data

        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('users.account'))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.firstname.data = current_user.firstname
        form.lastname.data = current_user.lastname
        form.email.data = current_user.email

    return render_template('account.html', form=form)
```

```
#forms.py
class UpdateUserForm(FlaskForm):

    email = StringField('Email',validators=[InputRequired(message = 'Enter a valid email'),Email()])
    firstname = StringField('First Name',validators=[InputRequired(message = 'Enter your first name')])
    lastname = StringField('Last Name',validators=[InputRequired(message = 'Enter your last name')])
    submit = SubmitField('Update')

    def validate_email(self,email):
        if User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('This email has been registered already!')
```

```
# Summarized Template & Form Submission

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="account" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="account-tab">
      <div class="col-5">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="small mb-0">{{ form.firstname.label }}</label>
            {{ form.firstname(class="form-control") }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="small mb-0">{{ form.lastname.label }}</label>
            {{ form.lastname(class="form-control") }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="small mb-0">{{ form.email.label }}</label>
            {{ form.email(class="form-control") }}
          </div>
          {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
# Model.py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    selected_theme = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False,default='default')
    email = db.Column(db.String(64),unique=True,index=True)
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __init__(self,email,fullname,password, firstname, lastname):
        self.email = email
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash,password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Username {self.username}"
```

Comment: Your current code appears correct at first glance. Can you add the code of the template to your question?

Comment: Added both template and model.py. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't find a mistake. The following code works for me. Even if there is no real difference to yours, it is worth trying.

```
class UpdateUserForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(
        'Email',
        validators=[
            # InputRequired is deprecated and replaced by DataRequired
            DataRequired(message = 'Enter a valid email'),
            Email()
        ]
    )
    firstname = StringField(
        'First Name',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(message = 'Enter your first name')
        ]
    )
    lastname = StringField(
        'Last Name',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(message = 'Enter your last name')
        ]
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Update')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        if User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('This email has been registered already!')
```

```
    @users.route("/account", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def account():
        # You can forward your current data to the form here
        form = UpdateUserForm(request.form, obj=current_user)
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            current_user.firstname = form.firstname.data
            current_user.lastname = form.lastname.data
            current_user.email = form.email.data
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('users.account'))
        return render_template('account.html', **locals())
```

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.email.label() }}
        {{ form.email(class='form-control') }}
        {% if form.email.errors: %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ form.email.errors[0] }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.firstname.label() }}
        {{ form.firstname(class='form-control') }}
        {% if form.firstname.errors: %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ form.firstname.errors[0] }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.lastname.label() }}
        {{ form.lastname(class='form-control') }}
        {% if form.lastname.errors: %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ form.lastname.errors[0] }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-primary') }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! Was able to resolve my issue by including the following updated to ignore the email submission if it is unchanged (I think it was recognized as a duplicate record and preventing unique value). This little addition seems to resolve.

```
def validate_email(self,email):
     if User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first() and email.data != current_user.email:
          raise ValidationError('Email has been already been registered.')
```

Comment: Uniqueness, without changing the value, of course I did not think about it. Nicely done.